# Inverse Fourier transform of $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin(s)}{s(\mu^2+s^2)}$

Tags: fourier-transform

This is based on a previous post of mine: [Question concerning the setup and process of solving an ODE.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909890/question-concerning-the-setup-and-process-of-solving-an-ode)

Here, I am specifically looking for advice on how to compute \begin{equation}
\tag{$*$}
\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin(s)}{s(\mu^2+s^2)}\right),
\end{equation}
where $\mu$ is a positive constant.
I know I can apply linearity to get $$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(s)}{s(\mu^2+s^2)}\right),$$ but I'm struggling to understand how to proceed from here. Using the convention that $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(g(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)e^{isx}ds,$$ the constant coefficient becomes $\frac{1}{\pi}$, so $(*)$ becomes
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(s)e^{isx}}{s(\mu^2+s^2)}ds.$$
Unfortunately, I'm a bit lost on how to actually evaluate this. My initial though was to expand $\sin(s)$ as a Taylor series, but this doesn't appear to be productive.

Comment: You could use the convolution theorem: the inverse Fourier transform of $$\frac{\mu}{\mu^2+s^2}\\ \frac{\sin(as)}{as} = \operatorname{sinc}(as)$$ are well known

Comment: @DavideMorgante So, write the integrand as a convolution of two functions and then the solution is the product of the inverse Fourier transforms of the two functions?

Comment: The other way 'round: the integrand function is the product of two functions with well-known Fourier (inverse) transforms, hence the integral is a convolution. The convolution between a Laplace distribution and the characteristic function of a symmetric interval, as already stated.

Comment: Alternatively, you may just invoke the residue theorem by carefully dealing with the cases $x<-1, x\in(-1,0), x\in(0,1), x>1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Okay, so I have $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f\cdot g)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)*\mathcal{F}^{-1}(g)$, correct? I'm struggling to see what my $f$ and $g$ are here, as Laplace distribution and characteristic function of a symmetric interval are foreign concepts to me.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Why do we have $4$ cases? I see that we need to have $\Im(s) x >0$ for a semicircle contour, but that will give only $2$ case.

Comment: That is true, it is sufficient to separate $|x|<1$ and $|x|>1$. @Atsina: I am just talking about $ \mu e^{-\mu|x|}$ and the function which equals $1$ on $[-1,1]$ and $0$ anywhere else.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio But why do we need to separate the $|x|>1$ and $|x| <1$?

Comment: Because the magnitude of $|x|$ chooses the correct integration contour (semi-circle) for $\frac{(e^{is}-e^{-is})e^{isx}}{2is(\mu^2+s^2)}$.

Comment: Thank you @JackD'Aurizio, I forgot to take care of the $\sin$!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Okay, I think I follow. $f=sinc(s)$ and $g=\frac{1}{\mu^2+s^2}$, so my solution is given by the convolution of the inverse Fourier transforms of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @Atsina: exactly.

Comment: You can evaluate the transform as
$$\mathcal F^{-1} \!\left[ \frac {\mu^2} {s (s^2 + \mu^2)} \right] =
\mathcal F^{-1} \!\left[ \frac 1 s - \frac s {s^2 + \mu^2} \right] = \\
\mathcal F^{-1} \!\left[ \frac 1 s \right] +
 i \frac d {dx} \mathcal F^{-1} \!\left[ \frac 1 {s^2 + \mu^2} \right] =
i \sqrt {\frac \pi 2} (1 - e^{-\mu |x|}) \operatorname{sgn} x, \\
\mathcal F^{-1} [F(s) \sin s] =
\frac 1 {2 i} (\mathcal F^{-1} [F](x + 1) - \mathcal F^{-1} [F](x - 1)).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, my hint is as follows: just remember that the convolution theorem takes this form for the product of two functions

> $$\mathcal F^{-1} \{fg\} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\mathcal F^{-1}\{f\}*\mathcal F^{-1}\{g\}\right)$$

In our case the functions we're dealing with are:

$$
f(s) = \frac{1}{\mu^2+s^2}\\[10pt] g(s) = \frac{\sin(s)}{s}
$$

which have very well known Fourier transforms, as mantiond by [Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44121/jack-daurizio)

$$
\begin{align}
&\mathcal F^{-1}\left\{\frac{\mu}{\mu^2+s^2}\right\} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-\mu|x|}&\textit{Laplace distribution}\\[10pt]
&\mathcal F^{-1}\left\{\frac{\sin\left(as\right)}{as}\right\} =\frac{1}{a\sqrt{2\pi}}\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{x}{2\pi a}\right)&\textit{Function of a symmetric interval}
\end{align} 
$$

You can find more information on the rectangular function at this wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function)

Comment: I understand why $\frac{\sin(s)}{s}$ has the same inverse Fourier transform as $\frac{\sin(as)}{s}$, but it's not clear to me why $\frac{1}{\mu^2+s^2}$ has the same inverse Fourier transform as $\frac{\mu}{\mu^2+s^2}$.

Comment: $\mu$ is just a number after all, you could just take it out of the transform and moving it to the RHS

Comment: Oh, sure. Thank you. Is a closed form solution to this convolution available?

Comment: Probably there is! Might be quite ugly though... I think that this is a work for @JackD'Aurizio that is very much more practical than me in finding closed form solutions :P